# Deserialize Enum from Xml using Value property in c#

Tags: c#, xml, enums, deserialization

I am trying to write an ONIX for book import tool in C#. I started by creating the classes using Xsd2Code and got a huge file with all the properties which after a few tweaks does not produce any error upon deserializing.

I am trying to deserialize an entire  element in one go, into a big object in memory and then do stuff with it (such as save it to database).

The way the Xsd2Code generated the classes, apart from the fact that there are A LOT of properties, are a bit weird, at least to me.

Here's one of the classes which should be a property of the Product object:

```
public partial class NotificationType
{
    public NotificationTypeRefname refname { get; set; }
    public NotificationTypeShortname shortname { get; set; }

    public SourceTypeCode sourcetype { get; set; }

    public List1 Value { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to direct your attention to this line:

```
    public List1 Value { get; set; }
```

"List1" is an enum, defined like so:

```
public enum List1
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnum("01")]
    Item01,

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnum("02")]
    Item02, etc...
```

My problem is that during deserialization, all fields deserialize correctly EXCEPT the Enums.

I tried decorating the properties with XmlEnum("NotificationType") etc... nothing!

This is my deserialization code:

```
var p = new Product();
XmlSerializer pserializer = new XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
object pDeserialized = pserializer.Deserialize(reader);
p = (Product) pDeserialized;
```

This is how this element looks like in XML:

```
<NotificationType>03</NotificationType>
```

The property that is in C# for the Product object is:

```
public NotificationType NotificationType { get; set; }
```

If I change this to:

```
public List1 NotificationType { get; set; }
```

the deserialization correctly shows 'Item03', meaning it does read whatever is in XML. IF I leave it like above, the 'Value' property of the NotificationType class is never filled, and always shows Item01 (the default of the Enum).

I have exhausted all possible questions on SO and web searches as to WHY this Value property works with some types (Strings) but not Enums. Am I missing something?

Sorry for the long question and code. Appreciate any light anyone can shed on this issue. Been stuck with it for a whole day now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]` to the `public List1 Value { get; set; }` property.

Comment: This works! I could swear I have tried it before. I think this is the attribute that lets the deserialization library know what property to fill as the value of the XML element.

Comment: Crazy, I'm working on ONIX too! This same thing works great for me too, for a single Enum value. Any luck with deseralizing an array of Enums? Such as List91[] ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public partial class NotificationType
{
    public NotificationTypeRefname refname { get; set; }
    public NotificationTypeShortname shortname { get; set; }
    public SourceTypeCode sourcetype { get; set; }

    public List1 Value { get {
        return (List1)Enum.Parse(typeof(List1), 
            Enum.GetName(typeof(List1), int.Parse(List1Value) - 1));
    }}

    [XmlText]
    public string List1Value { get; set; }
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

Since:

1. I also tried at first decorating the member with the `XmlText` attribute, but the following exception was occurring:

   > Cannot serialize object of type
   >   'ConsoleApplication1.NotificationType'. Consider changing type of
   >   XmlText member 'ConsoleApplication1.NotificationType.Value' from
   >   ConsoleApplication1.List1 to string or string array.
2. and you would like to avoid my initial approach in the answer,

the real solution is that, besides applying the `XmlText` attribute to `Value`,  all the other members should be decorated with the `XmlIgnoreAttribute`. I believe that using `XmlText` alone is not a guaranteed solution, as the results depend on the existence of other members.

```
public class NotificationType
{
    [XmlIgnore] // required
    public NotificationTypeRefname refname { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore] // required
    public NotificationTypeShortname shortname { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore] // required
    public SourceTypeCode sourcetype { get; set; }

    [XmlText] // required
    public List1 Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Voted up, this also works but in a less direct way. I don't really like to introduce an extra property for each case as there are about 200 of these in the ONIX specification.

Comment: @CristiCotovan, I also have an `InvalidOperationException` when I try pbz's answer. His answer was my first try, but it failed (and it still fails), so I looked for a workaround.

Comment: It works here, I don't know why it failed for you. I prefer it this way as it's cleaner and I am adding other things on top (such as Describing each Enum variant and extracting that using Reflection for displaying user-friendly meaning for each Enum value).

Comment: Was just trying to figure it out now, yes, your update does work. If those other properties are not ignored. I forgot that the first time I checked those properties were commented out. Well done!

Comment: Your last update works apart from cases where there are TWO properties in the same class that need to be deserialized from the XML, like is a case I just came across. A class contains two properties: 
    
        public List74 language { get; set; } and         
        public string Value { get; set; }

Comment: What is the XML for that? Maybe you should go with my first approach?

Comment: My sample XML does not include it, but I have the classes defined that way for a few instances. I think I should favor the 'Value' property with the XmlTextAttribute and leave the 'language' alone.

Comment: For further reference, maybe you should also remember that [_Only one instance of the XmlTextAttribute class can be applied in a class_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute(v=vs.71).aspx).